# WebdriverJS ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and I think I'm just not understanding what is happening in the code and browser.  I can work around my issue by replacing the driver.wait code (posted below) with a `driver.sleep(1000)` but I have been reading that sleep statements aren't ideal.

Can somebody help me figure out why the code I have isn't working and what exactly is going on?  I can provide a full stack trace if it is helpful.

Here is what the code looks like.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const By = webdriver.By
const until = webdriver.until

var username = "XXX"
var password = "XXX"

function login(username, password) {    
    // This part works fine
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Email')))
    driver.findElement(By.id('Email')).sendKeys(username)
    driver.findElement(By.id('next')).click()

    // Here is where the element not visible happens
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Passwd')), 5000)
    // driver.sleep(1000) works but I'm not sure why?
    driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd')).sendKeys(password)

    // Login
    driver.findElement(By.id('signIn')).click()
}

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome'}).build()
driver.get('https://gmail.com')
login(username, password)
```

**Update:**

Per suggestion, I tried using the `elementIsVisible` function to wait for the element to become visible, via the following code.

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd')), 5000))
```

But I get the following error.

> NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="Passwd"]"}

Comment: `.isEnabled()` usually applies only to `BUTTON` tags being disabled/enabled. You might try waiting for it to be visible or clickable.

Comment: Oh... and another comment. You want to keep functions doing a single thing... in this case, I would change `googeLogin()` to be just `login()` and take out the part where you set up the driver and navigate to google. Have it just handle the login portion.

Comment: @JeffC I cleaned up the code a little bit.  I removed the `isEnabled()` function but am still seeing the `element not visible` errors.

Comment: Have you tried to wait until the element is visible? e.g. `visibility_of_element_located`. See http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: I see a `elementIsVisible` in the docs http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html but get errors when I try to use it.  So far I've only been able to get `elementLocated` to work.

Comment: Just a quick update.  I was able to get a Python version working using `visibility_of_element_located` but it is still now working with Javascript/Node.js :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd')), 5000))

Actually this statement is not correct to wait until element is visible, in this statement `driver.findElement(By.id('Passwd'))` would throw `NoSuchElementError` if at that time element is not present on the `DOM` which you are getting.

You should try using [`until.elementLocated(locator)`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L237) to wait until desire element present on the `DOM` first, then wait until element is visible using [`until.elementIsVisible(element)`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.js#L301) below :-

```
const until = webdriver.until;

var pwd = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('Passwd')), 5000);
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(pwd), 5000)).sendKeys(password)
```